# MySQL - How to alter column datatype in all databases?

Tags: mysql, command-line, ddl

On my remote server, I need to update a column in a table in all databases. How can I do this all at once? I have over than hundred databases with the same table.

```
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY columnname VARCHAR(255);
```

Comment: I don't think you can with flat mysql command line or client. You are going to have to use at least a file containing all the databases names and a bash script. You can go with whichever language you use also. As a Rubyst I'll recommend you using the mysql2 gem and a simple ruby script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a SQL query to emit a script that does this. The query looks at the `information_schema` table describing columns in your server, and generates a sequence of `ALTER` queries. You then run those queries.

```
SELECT CONCAT(' ALTER TABLE `', TABLE_SCHEMA, '`.`', TABLE_NAME, 
              '` MODIFY `',COLUMN_NAME,'` VARCHAR(255);') ddl 
  FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` 
 WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tablename' 
   AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('columnname')
```

There isn't any oneliner to do `ALTER TABLE *.tablename` or anything like that.